# How to multi-level Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I Have this setup:

`Continent` -> `Country` -> `City` -> `Post`

and I Have

```
class Continent < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :countries
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :continent
  has_many :cities
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```

How do I get all the Continents having posts trough this associations

Like:

```
@posts = Post.all

@posts.continents #=> [{:id=>1,:name=>"America"},{...}]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Continent.all(:joins => {:countries => {:cities => :posts}}).uniq
```

Or this:

```
class Continent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :countries

  named_scope :with_post, :joins => {:countries => {:cities => :posts}}
end

# And then
Continent.with_post.uniq
```

Or this:

```
Post.all(:include => {:city => {:country => :continent}}).map { |post| post.city.country.continent }.uniq
```

Or this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city

  named_scope :include_continent, :include => {:city => {:country => :continent}}

  def continent
    city.try(:country).try(:continent)
  end
end

# And then
Post.include_continent.map(&:continent).uniq
```

Comment: Awesome! Didn't knew there is a built-in option to make nested joins in ActiveRecord! :)

Comment: hmmm, I get a syntax error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)` I suppose the interface has changed over the years.  search continues...